# Continuous function , unique solution

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b] $ , $f$ is continuous over $ [a,b]$ and  :

$\forall x_{1},x_{2} \in [a,b] ~~,~~~~ x_{1} \ne x_{2} ~~~~, ~~~~|f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})| < |x_{1}-x_{2} |    $

Prove that the equation $f(x) = x$ has only one solution .

I know that : $ |f'(x)| < 1 $ but it doesn't help me  to prove that $f$ is monotonous .

Comment: $f$ is not diffetentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x_1 \neq x_2$, $$f(x_1)=x_1$$

and $$f(x_2)=x_2$$

subtract the two equations

$$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=x_1-x_2$$

Take the absolute value and you should find a contradiction.

Edit: (Credit: thanks to @egreg and @SalahFatima for pointing out my mistake)

To prove existence of a solution,

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$, $g(a)=f(a)-a$, since $f(a) \geq a$, $g(a) \geq 0$.

Similarly, $g(b) \leq 0$.  Hence by intermediate value theorem, there is a value $c$ such that $g(c)=0$.

Comment: You're obviously not using continuity, which is possible because continuity *follows* from $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<|x_1-x_2|$.

Comment: I still end up using continuity to prove the existence of solution in the end.

Comment: Yes, for the existence continuity is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$.
$g$ is continuous at $[a,b]$.
$g(a)\geq 0, g(b)\leq 0$ thus

$\exists c_1\in[a,b]\;:\: g(c_1)=0$ or $f(c_1)=c_1$.

Suppose there exist an other $c_2$ such that $f(c_2)=c_2$. then

$|c_1-c_2|<|f(c_1)-f(c_2)|<|c_1-c_2|$ which is not possible.

Comment: I don't think existence of solution is guaranteed, can you check the counter example that I proposed? I can't think of how to prove $g(a) \geq 0$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh $f$ is from $[a,b]$ to $[a,b]$

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment.